# My language-region translation files are not recognized under the right directories for languages with multiple regions android

Tags: android, localization

I have localization in my app.
Now i have languages with regions attached to it like es_ES & es_MX, fr_FR & fr_CA

I have  created resource value folder as values-es-rES & values-es-rMX,
values-fr-rFR &  values-fr-rCA.

Also,  in my app user can select these languages from app itself.

For that we are setting locale in our app.

```
    private Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    if (Utility.isAtLeastVersion(JELLY_BEAN_MR1)) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return context;
}
```

the language codes being set to change app language is  es_ES & es_MX, fr_FR & fr_CA.

But these language codes are mot picking languages from respective folders.

if the language code is only "fr" and values folder is values-fr it works.

How to amke the app work with language code with regions

Answer (score 1):

You should specify language region when creating locale by `new Locale(language, country);`

```java
private Context updateResources(
    Context context, 
    String language,
    String country
) {
    // Locale locale = new Locale(language);

    // create locale for region
    Locale locale = new Locale(language, country);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);      

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    if (Utility.isAtLeastVersion(JELLY_BEAN_MR1)) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    return context;
}
```

**/!\ Attention**: If you are using `resourceConfigurations` to get rid of unused languages, you have to keep those regional resources.

```
// build.gradle.kts

android {
    defaultConfig {
        resourceConfigurations += setOf(
            "en", ...
            "fr", "fr-rFR", "fr-rCA",
            "es", "es-rES", "es-rMX", ...
        )
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.